# Giving up before even starting: life without a PhD

Tags: phd, industry, motivation

I am currently a Master student working on my thesis (started a few days ago). I've always wanted to become a researcher (thus getting a PhD) but a few months ago I started doubting about this decision and about my potential. Now that I'm working on my thesis, this feeling is getting just stronger and stronger. I thus came to the conclusion that I'm most probably just a mediocre *researcher* that would most probably be able to get accepted into a barely mediocre graduate school (I'm in Europe), even if my grades are quite strong. At this point there isn't much I can do, like getting a degree that would lead me more easily to getting a job in Industry, so I'm quite worried about my future and I lost all my motivation.

So, my question is: how likely it is, for a mediocre (Master) student and if we don't consider getting a PhD, to be able to get a job in Industry (like R&D department) in fields like data science or bioinformatics? If you will: what's the point of producing mediocre (research) results?

I read a lot of questions on this community about people in the middle of their PhD having similar doubts, but in this case I haven't even started it, so probably it's not a duplicate question.

Comment: Many people have jobs without any school education, or a degree or a masters let alone a PhD...

Comment: That's probably true. But in fields like data *something*, it's getting really hard to find a position that does not require some advanced experience (PhD or lots of previous experience).

Comment: Most people who have ever lived didn't have a PhD. And look where it got us... On the other hand, being a mediocre researcher doesn't mean you can't be a good academic. You could referee papers, teach, and administrate pretty well. All are important jobs in academia, and perhaps it is good to have mediocre researchers doing those jobs, while good researchers that are mediocre teachers are relegated to teaching fringe courses and spending more time on research. (Yes, some people are mediocre all across the board, or doing well all across the board. This is not a dichotomy.)

Comment: @Inkblot That’s also true, although it’s quite hard to accept considering I believed I would have become a good researcher someday!

Comment: You can still become a good researcher. You just need to find your niche. And even if you don't, as long as you don't let your ego stand in your way (like some people I knew that were bad researchers and crappy people), that's fine.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant here, but most people end up hating their work when they're writing their thesis -- it's really common, and doesn't necessarily say anything about you or your work.

Comment: @iayork Possibly, but I've been *working* on it for like 7 days! :)

Comment: Working on your thesis for only seven days? That's a very short time...

Comment: Are you *sure* you're mediocre? When I was in the midst of a master's, it was very hard to accurately assess myself. Everyone else's research seemed so sophisticated, and mine seemed so simple. But I trusted my supervisor's assurance that I was doing well. And in hindsight, he was right. My research only seemed simple to me because I understood it so well. Now, when I compare my thesis to those of other master's students, I can judge it more fairly, and I'm proud of my work.

Comment: There are lots of job in health care and government available with a masters in stats.  Yes, you don't have the killer degree (Ph.D.) but there are lots of simpler jobs available.  They can be quite rewarding, also.

Answer (score 3):

**It's quite likely you'll be able to get a job in industry with a mediocre Masters**.

Think about it this way: there's a sizable population that never finish their Bachelor's degree. Among those that did complete their Bachelor's, a sizable fraction never do a Masters. In other words, you are already quite rare. So you'll probably be able to get a job in industry, if only because you don't have many competitors. Another way to think about it is, given that you're doing Masters, I'll guess that you did quite well during your Bachelor's. Odds are you know people who did worse than you (i.e. had "mediocre grades"). Did they manage to get a job? You can check, although I predict the answer is "yes". They might not have gotten their dream job or one that pays as much as they want, but they got something.

It sounds like you are asking this question because you're unfamiliar with the job market. Therefore I suggest searching for jobs in your vicinity that require a Masters degree in whatever field you're studying. It's imperative to know, because then you'll have some idea of what you're going to be working as after you graduate. If you find there're lots of vacancies, your chances of getting a job goes up.

One more thing: don't view not getting a PhD as "giving up". I know quite a few PhD holders who, in retrospect, think they should *not* have gotten a PhD.

> What's the point of producing mediocre (research) results?

I don't know, do you? If you don't know either, why are you even considering it? You're in charge of your own happiness; you have to alter your own fate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By reading this and the comments, I am realizing that it’s not really not being able to get a PhD, rather accepting mediocrity in research. And yes, I have no idea how the job market works! Again, thank you.